# Sprout Forms - Can't save front end entry edits

Tags: craft3, plugin-sproutforms, frontend-form

This this might be a bug but want to ask here first in case I'm missing something minor.

#### Description

Trying to front edit a Sprout Form entry that was created in the front end. I'm using the same form code with additional `<input type="hidden" name="entryId" value="###">` field. But it doesn't save the entry, it creates a new entry.

I compared my form fields with plugin backend and think I have everything I need:

```
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="sprout-forms/entries/save-entry">
<input type="hidden" name="handle" value="handle_name">
<input type="hidden" name="entryId" value="275">
```

#### Steps to reproduce

1. Create form entry
2. Edit in front end
3. Submit form
4. Original entry is unchanged and there's a new entry

#### Additional info

- Craft version: Craft CMS 3.0.18
- PHP version: 7.2.1
- Database driver & version: MySQL 5.6.34
- Plugins & versions: Sprout Forms 3.0.0-beta.20

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Craft 3

This feature is available in Sprout Forms for Craft 3 (since v3.0.0-beta.22).

The feature is disabled by default and can be enabled in the Sprout Forms settings.

#### Craft 2

This feature exists in Sprout Forms for Craft 2 via the `enableEditFormEntryViaFrontEnd` config override.